# How can chlorine form ClO2?

Tags: lewis-structure

Doesn't it have only have one bonding electron?

Then how can it bond with 2 oxygens?

The Lewis structure doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Not all molecules have reasonable Lewis structures (nor must they), consider $\ce{NO}$. In this case, some of the lone pairs participate in the bonding, if memory serves.

Comment: In this case most notably, you are dealing with a free radical.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/speculation-about-chlorine-dioxide-isomer